# What is the equivalent of the following directories in relation to windows for ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem

I'm still learning the linux file system and understanding where everything is installed. I'm coming from windows mindset and would like to wrap my head around the following directory equivalents:

What is the following directory equivalent in ubuntu or just linux in general as im assuming its the same:

```
c:\program files  --- Where all the programs are installed.
c:\windows --- Main OS core files.
c:\Users --- Where all the users data reside
c:\ --- All the startup / bootup files (config.sys / autoexec.bat)
```

--- What other important directories should I know about to fully understand the ubuntu/linux file system structure?